# Regex - find everything between <td> tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get everything between (and ) tags using regex. I am new to this, but I have tried the following

```
$html = file_get_contents($inputUrl);
preg_match_all('<td>([^"]*)</td>/', $html, $result);

foreach ($result as $val) {
    print $val."<br>";
}
```

I think the syntax of my regex is wrong. I get the following error:

> Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier
>   '(' in C:...\tester.php on line 5
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:...\tester.php
>   on line 7

Btw I need to use regex for this task! So I don't need any suggestions about using "parse XML" etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: A better way may be... `$dom = new DOMDocument; $dom->loadHTML( $html );`

Comment: What if you have nested `<td>` tags? Do you want to get all the different `<td>` or the outermost one?

Comment: Aaron: Like I wrote in my question: "I need to use regex for this task!", but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following working code :

```
$mpmatch = "!<td>(.*?)</td>!is";
$str = "<td>sdfdfdfdsfds</td><td>333333333</td>";
preg_match_all($mpmatch, $str, $result);
foreach ($result as $val) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($val);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: !<td>(.*?)</td>!is was actually better, the /<TD>([^"]*)<\/td>/ dind't really fix my problem. thanks!

Comment: its because of the is added to the end of the regex, it is used for case insensitive matching

Answer (score 2):

You missed first delimeter and you need to escape `/` or use different delimeter

```
   preg_match_all('/<td>([^"]*)<\/td>/', $html, $result);
                   ^----
```

Or:

```
   preg_match_all('#<td>([^"]*)</td>#', $html, $result);
```

Also, you need use greedy match:

```
   preg_match_all('#<td>(.*?)</td>#s', $html, $result);
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it.

Comment: ahh yes of course thanks a lot Jason.. and Richard i guess :) btw do u know why my question got voted down, i dont get it :/

Comment: I ended up using "!<td>(.*?)</td>!" which solved the problem completely.

Comment: ok but my answer posted one hour earlier that the one you accepted!