# Search for all [{my value here}] and put them in an array in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following HTML code below, which acts as a template for a module on my php application. The following HTML code is stored as the string:

```
$parsedTemplate
```

Here is the HTML

```
<td>
    [{item3}]
</td>

<td>
    [{item2}]
</td>

<td>
    [{item3}]
</td>
```

I want php to search the $parsedTemplate string and make an array like the following

```
'item1','item2','item3'
```

How can I achieve this in an efficient way? Regex maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - find everything between <td> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999929/regex-find-everything-between-td-tags)

Comment: Not what I am after. I don't want it to be specific to <td> tags.

Comment: What are the delimiters here and what is fixed constant in the way of tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?s)\[{\K.*?(?=}])
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dD8uH1/2)

Explaining:

```
(?s)      # allows . to match new line
\[{       # your open-delimiter
\K        # you do not need the delimiter, then clear it
.*?       # till the first-next occurrence where
(?=}])    # is possible to see the close-delimiter
```

Hope it helps.

---

**Edit**: To test, it would be like:

```
preg_match_all('/(?s)\[{\K.*?(?=}])/', $parsedTemplate, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I need. Very tidy and clean way to do it.

Comment: @DanWinter-Wijntjes. Glad to help :)